# Not able to use unorered_map or unodered_set on mac

Tags: c++, macos

When using

```
unordered_map<int,int> mp;
```

or

```
unordered_set<int> s;
```

,I am getting the following error on mac :

***error: no template named 'unordered_map'***

Output for  gcc --version :

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.29)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin20.4.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin
```

Code :

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;


int main(){
    unordered_map<int,int> mp;
    mp[1] = 2;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `-std=c++11` is required. gcc is an alias for clang, and it defaults to C++98 on a mac.

Comment: gcc doesn't have that.

Comment: *That*, being what exactly?

Comment: You're going to have to show some code if the compiler flag doesn't fix the issue. You're supposed to read [ask] and [mre] at a minimum before posting your first question.

Comment: @sweenish , I am novice so couldn't get it. What exactly should I do?
Also, the code is just a simple line in main (update in the question)

Comment: My first comment is a compiler flag. At a minimum, your compile command should be `clang++ -Wall -Wextra -std=c++11 <FILENAME>`.  I will also say that wherever you're learning from, stop and find a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) instead. Your first line is implementation-dependent (not good), and your second line is bad practice.

Comment: thank you @sweenish for the resource. By the way, the code worked when I included unordered_map header instead of bits/stdc++.h. Thanks for the suggestion